# Python - remap the values according to date

Tags: python

I have 3 `tsv` files with different stock values on a slight different date. I need to compile all 3 stock values into 1 `tsv` file according to date. The problem is the 3 files have slight different date. For example,

```
Stock1:
23 july 2009 - 10.03
24 july 2009 - 10.07
25 july 2009 - (no value)

Stock2:
23 july 2009 - (no value)
24 july 2009 - 3.07
25 july 2009 - 3.10

Stock3:
23 july 2009 - 5.40
24 july 2009 - (no value)
25 july 2009 - 5.10
```

As you can see, there are sometimes no value available. I want to make it into:

```
compiledStocks:
Date:          Stock1       Stock2       Stock3 
23 july 2009 - 10.03,       (no value),  5.40
24 july 2009 - 10.07,       3.07,        (no value)
25 july 2009 - (no value),  3.10,        5.10
```

What is the best way to loop through all 3 files with `Python` and compile it into a single file?

Comment: better to express your need other than saying *best*, otherwise your question may be closed for being primarily opinion-based

Comment: you should add an example of your data and what you expect (and what you tried)...

Comment: Do you have one stock or several stocks per file? Are you allowed to use non-standard python modules (e.g. numpy and pandas)?

Comment: ya different stocks in different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas`, as you have mentioned its a `tsv` hope it helps:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('filepath/stock1',sep='\t')
df
Out[31]: 
              0      1
0  23 july 2009  10.03
1  24 july 2009  10.07
2  25 july 2009    NaN
```

Similarly for the other two files as:

```
df2=pd.read_csv('filepath/stock2',sep='\t')
df2
Out[42]: 
              0     1
0  23 july 2009   NaN
1  24 july 2009  3.07
2  25 july 2009  3.10

df3=pd.read_csv('filepath/stock3',sep='\t')
df3
Out[43]: 
              0    1
0  23 july 2009  5.4
1  24 july 2009  NaN
2  25 july 2009  5.1
```

then using pandas [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
In[56]:df4=df1.merge(df2,on=0,how='left').merge(df3,on=0,how='left').rename(columns={0:'Date','1_x':'Stock1','1_y':'Stock2',1:'Stock3'}).fillna('No value')

df4
Out[57]: 
           Date    Stock1    Stock2    Stock3
0  23 july 2009     10.03  No value       5.4
1  24 july 2009     10.07      3.07  No value
2  25 july 2009  No value       3.1       5.1
```

Comment: I am getting a `KeyError: 0`. Do the `Date` in all 3 files must be absolutely the same? is it ok if there is a missing date, which is in my case?

Comment: I figure out the error. I have to change the `sep` from `\t` to `,` because mine is `,`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question how to iterate multiple files, use `fileinput.input()`.

```
with fileinput.input(files=('spam.txt', 'eggs.txt')) as f:
    for line in f:
        process(line)
```